# Read password using perl on windows

Tags: perl, stty

We have a perl script, in the we read password using stty. As stty is not available on windows this script fails. We did some search and found that ReadKey is an alternative for this. However we dont have this package shipped by default.

Is there any way to read password in perl without using stty and ReadKey?

It will be of great help if someone can help me in this regard.

Comment: Can you clarify this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read *password* you can also use [Term::ReadLine](http://search.cpan.org/~kjalb/TermReadKey-2.14/ReadKey.pm).

For further details visit [Perl Monk](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=352298).